# Which is better in production environment, jar or war?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I use spring boot and which is better to have in production environment, `jar` or `war`?

Production environment has Tomcat and Weblogic.

Comment: What do you have in production? Any application server, images, container, any cloud provider? War requires application server... Spring-boot jar contains tomcat embedded

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you deploy the software in production,

- If you use an **external** application server, like Apache Tomcat for example, which is installed in a production environment, then I would probably say `war`.
- If you use the **embedded** application server provided by spring-boot, I would say `jar`. This scenario is most common in cloud production environments or when your result will be a docker image.
- I have also seen in the past the deployment of a web Java project by directly copying the build result from the `target` directory of the project (using for example `mvn package`) to the production Tomcat. I mean by copying the directories WEB-INF, META-INF etc from your `target/artifactId-version` directory to the production location `tomcat-home/webapps/ROOT/` directory (or whichever the root directory of your project is located in production -  if you use virtual hosts).

I am not an expert in devops and cloud technologies, this is my opinion in this generic question. If you add more information about your production environment you will probably receive more specific answers.